# how can i decode this page using C#

Tags: c#, stream, iostream

this is the page url :http://product.dangdang.com/callback.php?type=detail&product_id=20945731&page_type=book

i downloaded the source as a stream or a file .
how can i decode it using c# stream ? and get content of the json .

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to try this [json-c#-class-generator](http://at-my-window.blogspot.com/2010/11/json-c-class-generator.html), so you can pass this stream to initialize the object tree and then just consume it. I have tried it with a **HUGE** json, and everything went great!!!!!!

**EDIT:** You wont even have to pass this Stream object, you may pass the JSON raw string, and youll have the job done!!! see;

```
public List<Result> HandleRequest(String json)
{
        RootObject ro = new RootObject(json); //This line solved the problem, as now it become totally easy to consume this JSON as C# objects...
}
```

Comment: great thanks !  

i tested it , it's great !

is it written by u ?

Comment: No man, its not, but its totally useful! haha If it helps you solving your problem, please select my answer and give an upvote hahaha!!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: thanks again 
" Vote up requires 15 reputation "
currently i can't do this

Comment: I think you have 16 reputation, am I wrong? hahah Please accept the answer at least. Thank you very much!